# What is the use of the EXIT keyword?

Tags: cobol

I've seen many COBOL programs contain sections with at the end

```
XX-99.
    EXIT.
```

Many times that paragraph is used to exit the section, for instance with `GO TO XX-99`. I have read that `EXIT` is a no-operation, as it doesn't do anything. But the same goes for `CONTINUE`. One could easily replace `EXIT` with `CONTINUE`. Alternatively, one could replace `GO TO XX-99` with `EXIT SECTION`.

Is there any compelling reason to use `EXIT` rather than `CONTINUE`? Why was `EXIT` introduced anyway? Was `EXIT` introduced before `CONTINUE` was?

---

Note: I'm not talking about `EXIT` in combination with another reserved word, like `EXIT PROGRAM` or `EXIT PERFORM`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any compelling reason to use EXIT rather than CONTINUE?
> Why was EXIT introduced anyway?
> Was EXIT introduced before CONTINUE was?

There is no "compelling" reason to choose one over the other. There is no practical difference. The reason to choose `EXIT` over `CONTINUE` is conformance to existing coding standards.

`EXIT` was part of the original [COBOL 60 Report](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_codasylCOB_6843924/mode/2up) where it was a "Compiler Directing Verb." Its purpose was to mark the end of a performed procedure, directing the compiler to transfer control to the statement following the invoking `PERFORM` statement or to the `PERFORM` statement for the next iteration of a loop.

In the ANSI COBOL 68 standard, it became a statement to mark the end of a performed procedure. It was no longer required, since the end of the perform range was the end of the last (or only) performed paragraph or section. It remained as a convenient target for a `GO TO` statement.

[With the introduction of the `SORT` statement, an `EXIT` statement may also be used to mark the end of an input or output procedure.]

`CONTINUE` was introduced in the 1985 standard as part of the changes for structured programming. It purpose was to replace the `NEXT SENTENCE` statement used within the `IF` and `SEARCH` statements or wherever an imperative statement is required by a statement format, but nothing need be done. It is in this last use that a `CONTINUE` statement may be used to replace an `EXIT` statement.

`EXIT SECTION` was introduced in the 2002 standard.

Answer (score 3):

The 2014 standard still says:

> The `EXIT` statement provides a common end point for a series of procedures [...]
> [it] shall appear in a sentence by itself that shall be the only sentence in the paragraph [...]
> [and] serves only to enable the user to assign a procedure-name to a given point in a procedure division.
> Such an `EXIT` statement has no other effect on the compilation or execution.

Even in COBOL 202x this format it still is not marked archaic (while the `EXIT PROGRAM` format is, because of the same functionality provided by `GOBACK`).

With its different syntax rules to the `CONTINUE` statement it is already not the same (though some COBOL compilers don't enforce this rule and some of those also don't have an option to even create a warning if this rule is broken).

Concerning the originating: COBOL-74 does not seem to have a `CONTINUE` statement (at least my copy of VAX-11 COBOL-74 does not list it), it seems to have come in together with the inline format of the `PERFORM` statement in COBOL-85.

I personally would also prefer the procedure format of `EXIT` (`EXIT SECTION` or even `EXIT PARAGRAPH` if no sections are used in the program) over a `GO TO`, but as always with COBOL: follow whatever your team-/house-rules are, some may also forbid those.

Comment: `continue` was introduced in Cobol 1985 along with `end-if`, in line performs and `evaluate`. It is need in `evaluate` for an empty `case`

Comment: @BruceMartin Well, an empty case looks useless to me, as omitting the case alltogether would cause the same effect, namely a no-operation. However, `continue` is, for example, useful for the body of an `invalid key` clause, as specifying this clause will prevent the runtime to exit with a file status error.

Comment: @MCEmperor it is useful in two ways, 1) prevents the execution of the OTHERWISE clause in an evaluate; 2) as a **get out of here**, If doing a `EVALUATE TRUE` you could do `When END-OF-FILE continue` all subsequent `WHEN` are only checked if you have record, the alternative might be a series of `WHEN (not END-OF-File) and ...`. It can simplify the logic